# Using session in wcf

Tags: wcf, session

If I set my servis instance as Per Session or Single can I send some data between services instance in session? It should be done in Asp.net session  - HttpContext.Current.Session
or wcf have own session ?

Comment: oK, I understand, but can I use Wcf session like asp and save data in it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I said - WCF is not ASP.NET and its session handling is vastly different. While ASP.NET sessions and WCF sessions are called the same - they are vastly different in their purpose and usefulness.

Read the MSDN page [Using Sessions in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) for more details.

One sentence reads: *There is no general data store associated with a WCF session.* - so the answer is no - sessions in WCF are **not** meant for data storage.

WCF sessions are merely to "tie together" several messages into a conversation. By default, with the "per-call" model, each WCF service request would get its own, freshly instantiated service class instance to handle the request, and that service class instance will be freed after returning the answer. Using sessions avoids this - the service class instance handling the first call of a session will stay alive on the server side (and thus also taking up memory on the server) and will handle all subsequent requests within the same session.

WCF and web services in general should however preferably be **stateless**, so sessions are a bit of an oddball architecture in a proper SOA environment - and that's most likely why sessions in WCF are also not nearly as useful as ASP.NET sessions are for web apps.

To remain stateless and support the per-call method (the preferred best practice), if you need to store data between calls, store it in a persistent store (e.g. a database) and fetch it back from there when needed later on.

Answer (score 5):

If you're hosting services in IIS, you can enable ASP.Net Compatability mode.  This will allow you to use ASP.Net session state, just like you would in a web application.

Comment: How do you enable ASP.Net Compatability mode?