# asp.net session state from non browser requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

probably a very silly question which you feel like asking on silly days.

A user visits a web page in an ASP.net application from a browser. A session state (and ID) gets established (In proc, db whatever) on the server. Pretty basic.

Now, does this happen if the request originated from a non-browser application, say a console application that does a post and retrieves the response.

Lets say I have a session variable set in the master page. Any page visits will cause this session variable to be set. What happens if a request is programatically issued to grab the response from a page? Is this session variable set or does the console app request have access to session?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I'm assuming it is only for browser requests?

> ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application. HTTP is a stateless protocol. This means that a Web server treats each HTTP request for a page as an independent request. The server retains no knowledge of variable values that were used during previous requests. ASP.NET session state identifies requests from the same browser during a limited time window as a session, and provides a way to persist variable values for the duration of that session. By default, ASP.NET session state is enabled for all ASP.NET applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the console application would be sending a HTTP POST to a web server. If that's the case, your console application is acting like a web browser, and Session is initialized. But ASP.NET normally sends the Session ID using a Cookie, so the browser (or console application) has to store that cookie to continue the session in a future HTTP request to that same HTTP server.

Comment: i'm not asking really about future requests. Say if the page request was doing things that depended on session being set from the master page, will the page have access to it? or in other words, will the programatic request act just like a browser request as far as session is concerned. I guess your answer indicates that it does.

Comment: How about if it was a WCF service exposed through the application (part of the project). Will the requests to it have access to the session considering it is part of the app domain?

Comment: @codernet In theory, yes. But, WCF's Session is a little different from ASP.NET (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917843/254973) so you may need to look into other options before depending on it.